# CSS missing in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Having a problem with this block of CSS:

```
#social-title
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 270 px;
    left: 575px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

When this renders in Firefox the div is at the top of the page. When I render it in Chrome, it is where it should be. However, when I use Firebug to look at this, the "top: 270px;" line is missing in Firefox but not in Chrome. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove space 
you are using `top: 270 px;`

please use

```
top: 270px;
```

Comment: This one is correct. In CSS units must come right after the value (no spaces or other symbols: 50%, 12pt, 1s). Your CSS is invalid, Chrome "forgives" it, but not Firefox. You can easily catch this kind of errors using [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input).

Comment: @MichaelMahony If this one answers your question accept it - there is a tick mark on the left.